# Create uncollected invoices (customers have 30 days to pay) in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, invoice, invoice-pdf

When I create an order manually for a customer who places his order over the phone, I need to create his PDF invoice in order to send it. But when I do this, the invoice is created already paid, but I need to create invoices for PDF orders and they are not paid because customers have 30 days to pay it. How can I do this? Any ideas?